# Unable to sort the element in nested json

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My json structure is like this:

```
0:
  day: "2020-03-14"
  total: {confirmed: 81, recovered: 9, deaths: 2, active: 70}
  statewise: Array(37)
    0: {state: "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", confirmed: 0, recovered: 0, deaths: 0, active: 0}
    1: {state: "Andhra Prad ......
```

These array are recorded daily. So for every date, I have this structure.

**Line 171-172:**

```
  var data = json_data.data.history[7].statewise;
  var data1 = json_data.data.history
```

Initially I was trying to use the particular date and draw a bar chart. But now I am trying this without doing it manually. I am using filter if date matches this date get this date array.

**Line 296-310:**

```
 let yearSlice = data1.filter(function(d) {
  // log("d.date::::::::",d, d.day, new Date(d.day), year, (new Date(d.day).getTime()===year.getTime()));
  return new Date(d.day).getTime()===year.getTime();
 })

  .sort(function(a,b){
    log("aaaaaaaaaA:",a);
    log("astatewise:", a.statewise);
    return d3.descending(a.confirmed, b.confirmed) ;})
  .slice(0, top_n);


  yearSlice.forEach(function(d,i)
  { log("dddddddddddD:",d.statewise[i].confirmed,i);
    return d.rank = i});
```

I am trying to sort by no of cases. So the first element will give me the state having maximum no of cases. and then I will do ranking of top 10 states.

But this `sort` function doesn't even work as there is no `console.log` output. Filtering does work but not the sort thing.

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Working demo with code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/2jwKNuxysNqvh707?preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to get the array like this:

```
 var yearSlice = data1.filter(function(d) {

  return new Date(d.day).getTime()===year.getTime();
 })[0].statewise;
```